# How to bind the selected value from jQuery datepicker to a Knockout Observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a to and from date range datepicker (jquery) that I am trying to bind the selected values to to knockout observables. 
The date pickers to and from limit the date range a user can select and defaults to the past 30 days once the user selects the "from" date.

I have bound two span element to test the bindings to the value of the observables however whenever I select a date the datepicker sets the fields appropriately but the observables are never triggered/updated.

**[Working Fiddle located here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/NKP9h/)**

html

```
From
<input type="text" id="StartDate" data-bind="value: myStartDate()" />to
<input type="text" id="EndDate"  data-bind="value: myEndDate()"/>
<hr/>
<p>start day<span data-bind="text: myStartDate()" />
</p>
<p>end day<span data-bind="text: myEndDate()" />
</p>
```

js (and ko combined)

```
var myViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myStartDate = ko.observable();
    self.myEndDate = ko.observable();
};
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());

//calendar controls
//setup min and max date ranges
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate());
//default range
var defRange = 30;
// total range 1yr +/-
var e = new Date();
var xDate = 365;
e.setDate(d.getDate() - xDate);

$('#StartDate').datepicker({
    maxDate: d,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('font-size', 10);
    },
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var dp2 = $('#EndDate');
        var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + xDate);
        //defaults to past 30 days
        dp2.datepicker('setDate', -defRange);
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - xDate);
        //set max date for start and end range
        dp2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
        dp2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    }
});

$('#EndDate').datepicker({
    maxDate: d,
    minDate: e,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('font-size', 10);
    }
});

$('#StartDate').focus(function () {
    $('#StartDate').datepicker('show');
});

$('#EndDate').focus(function () {
    $('#EndDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

Where I am stuck is in understanding what I need to do get the values set once a date is selected in the datepicker and populated to the input fields pushed across to the observables.

Thanks for any hints or suggestions,

Comment: Problem is, knockout and any 3rd party ui library aren't going to be compatible out of the box. With your example, the data-bind and the .datepicker initializer aren't talking to eachother at all...the datepicker object doesn't know what to do with your observable. Here's a thread to look at...https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/dtXftC1Ncgg/urob4cACH7EJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First of all you should use

```
 data-bind="value: myStartDate"
```

instead of

```
 data-bind="value: myStartDate()"
```

With this changes, second datepicker works as expected.

2) First datepicker doesn't work, because you set value manually (`.datepicker('setDate', ..);`)
You should trigger `change` event on inputs to update observables.

```
  /// 
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + xDate);
  $(this).change()  
  ///
  dp2.datepicker('setDate', -defRange);
  dp2.change();
  ///
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wr9La/)